# My OSM country roads network is not routable

Tags: qgis, postgis, grass-gis, pgrouting

I need a routable shapefile in order to execute pgrouting algorithms. I download a national zip from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/greece-latest.shp.zip and import the roads shapefile in my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database through QGIS. Then I execute the following SQL commands (following the workshop instructions):

```
ALTER TABLE roads ADD COLUMN length integer;
UPDATE roads SET length = st_length(st_transform(geom,2100));
ALTER TABLE roads ADD COLUMN reverse_cost double precision;
UPDATE roads SET reverse_cost = length;
ALTER TABLE roads ADD COLUMN "source" integer;
ALTER TABLE roads ADD COLUMN "target" integer;
SELECT pgr_createTopology('roads', 0.0005, 'geom', 'id');
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
            SELECT id AS id,
                     source::integer,
                     target::integer,
                     length::double precision AS cost
                    FROM roads',
            number1, number2, false, false);
```

where number1 and number 2 are values I define manually. All commands are executed with success but the last one. The query does not work in most cases, although there is an apparent road link, because, as I zoom in the layer, I can see breaks in the network. 
I searched similar problems in the forum and I found suggestions that I should fix my shapefile in order to make it routable. I tried the GRASS commands *split* and *clean* but I met problems. With *split* I had no result since it said it found too many errors. With *clean* I had a cleaned shapefile but a non-routable one again.

Is there another way to make my dataset routable?

Comment: For the record: The vector network maintenance command is v.net: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.html